# Lag GUI - Problem with Graphic Drivers

Tags: graphic-drivers

I've got big problem with proprietary drivers in elementary OS. I installed fglrx but it's doesn't work. GUI is very laggy when I go to menu..

When i type `sudo lshw -c video` it shows:

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Kabini [Radeon HD 8210]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:77 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0900000-f093ffff memory:f0960000-f097ffff
```

Please, help. :)

Comment: Does it behave the same way in ubuntu? or does it only affect Elementary?

Comment: Yes it does. I think it doesnt support 3D or something like that.
BTW. I working on Acer Aspire V5-122P. Maybe its too low-end.

Comment: My laptop use a radeon HD 5650 and works great. But the fglrx creates lots of trouble in my case. Now I use the xorg driver radeon and everything works beautiful. You should try it.

Comment: Stiffler - I've try that. Still lag... :c

Comment: Are you sure you are purging the entire fglrx driver and using the open source one?